# How do I vertically center the text in the header of a Google document?

Tags: google-docs

I'm using Google Docs, and I put some text in a header, and it is showing up very close to the top of the page. I want to position the text so that is vertically centered between the top of the page and the bottom of the top margin. For example, if the page has a top margin of 1", I want the text to show up around 0.5" from the very top of the page. This is similar to what Pages on OS X does by default. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this time, Google Documents doesn't have a vertical align setting for headers. The alternatives are

- Use line spacing, blank paragraphs, font size, etc.
- Insert a table as it has vertical align settings.
- Insert a drawing as its text shape has vertical align settings.